# Stop All Started Services on App Close / Exit

Tags: android

**Is it possible to stop all started services when the user hits the Home Button?**

I use:

```
startService(new Intent(ClassName.this, ClassName2.class));
stopService(new Intent(ClassName.this, ClassName2.class));
```

This means I will have to somehow add the 'stopService()' for 7+ of my app classes
I've researched this topic and I think there's 'onTerminate' but still not sure how this should be implemented.

Any help or hints would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is it possible to stop all started
>   services when the user hits the Home
>   Button?

Not directly. For starters, you have no way of knowing they pressed HOME.

If you only want the service running while activities are using it, consider getting rid of `startService()`. Instead, use `bindService()` in the `onStart()` methods of the activities that need the service, and call `unbindService()` in their corresponding `onStop()` methods. You can use `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` to have the service be lazy-started when needed, and Android will automatically stop the service after all connections have been unbound.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
This all makes sense, one thing though, is there more information on "BIND_AUTO_CREATE" ? I understand the 'service' concept, but still not sure how would I keep the music playing between my 7+ Activities, but stop it when user gets out to the 'Home Screen'. 

If anyone else has the same problem, I found a good article about Android services here: http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/01/basics-of-android-part-iii-android-services/

Comment: Your desired pattern will be difficult to implement. That's why most music players don't do what you do -- they specifically *want* the music playing when the user presses HOME, offering a Notification for rapid access back to the app to stop the music. In fact, it will be impossible for you to implement this pattern specifically for HOME. You can probably implement this pattern for "none of my activities are in the foreground", by keeping a flag of whether any of your activities are in the foreground, plus a watchdog that shuts the music if the flag is false for too long.

Comment: Yeah, this is just for a game, so when the game is suspended/paused the music will not play.
I noticed that I can use onPause() for it to stop playing if I press 'HOME' but the only problem is that it stops when I proceed in the game menu.
Any hints to solve this issue?

Comment: Just use a static class with static functions and static variables -- the static variables are preserved in between activity transitions and during app pause/restart. They survive as long as the app is running.

Comment: My suggestion above is also found here (non-persistent section): http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html

Comment: Android doesn't handle singletons and other static data structures well. Since singletons, by definition, might not have any reference pointing to them, the JVM sometimes collects them on low resources flows. So the best approach is a Service. Just manage it well.

Comment: Theo's idea works for many use cases, but it won't work when you want to stop the service when or otherwise clear out the static data when the app exits.

Comment: Rad The Mad: The problem you speak of is certainly different than using the approach outline by Commonsware. Have you figured out a good solution? I do not have a good solution, other than to put together a series of checks. For example: Always start the music playing service onPause, but DON'T do it, if the user is hitting back and the Activity is not root or if the user is going to another internal Activity. This may involve passing special parameters within the various Intents. OnResume always stop the service, unless a certain Intent variable is present. Phew. Sounds complicated eh?

Answer (score 2):

If you want services to stop when the user leaves your app, I would ask if you want to use services at all.  You may just be making your application way more complicated than it needs to be.

Also, this line is really questionable:

```
startService(new Intent(ClassName.this, ClassName2.class));
```

You are making an Intent whose action is the class name of one class, and data URI is the class name of another class...!  Maybe you mean something like "new Intent(context, MyService.class)"?

Comment: Thank you for your input, I'm just trying to have music playing in my app. I also have music/sound settings to turn it off and etc. 
I will also fix the "new Intent" part.

Comment: Okay.  You don't need a service to have music playing, though.