# How can my app reliably start a service on application exit?

Tags: android, android-service

When my app exits, I want to start a service and when the user restarts the app I want to stop it. However, there is no direct way for an app to tell when ALL of its Activities are finished.

This problem is hard because, the user could exit any `Activity` by pressing home or if they get an interruption like a phone call. So I cannot rely on the user exiting the root Activity to detect when to start the service.

So I plan to implement these measures:

- OnPause on all `Activities` `StartService` unless going to or from an Internal `Activity`. using `Intent` parameters to track.
- OnResume on all `Activities`: `StopService`

Is there a more elegant, more robust way to accomplish this?

this question has some hints:
[Stop All Started Services on App Close / Exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660613/stop-all-started-services-on-app-close-exit)

Comment: "When my app exits, I want to start a service and when the user restarts the app I want to stop it" -- ignoring the fact that this isn't especially practical (the user and OS have various ways to get rid of your service), and given that the user is not in your app 99% of the time, wouldn't it be simpler just to have the service running all of the time?

Comment: Good point, that is an option to consider

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Let me try to take a shot at this one..

Let create an `BaseActivity` extended from `Activity` and all your `Activities` should extend from this `BaseActivity`...

`Override` the `onDestroy()` in `BaseActivity` and in that check if the current process has any more active `Task` or `Activities`.. If it does not have any more active `Task` or `Activity` then start your `Service`..

Also override `onStart()` or `onCreate()` in `BaseActivity`and their check if this is the only active `Task` and `Activity`... if it is then stop your `Service`

Following API can be used to check if there are more active `Task` and/or `Activities` in app:

To get the list of running tasks:

```
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService    (Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE); 

   List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks= activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

To check if the task if from your app:

```
 for (RunningTaskInfo task : tasks) {
        if (getContext().getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase(task.baseActivity.getPackageName())) {
              //check activity
           }
    }
```

[`NumActivities`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.html#numActivities) property of `RunningTaskInfo` can be used to check the activities in the `Task`..

Hope it helps...

EDIT1: I like the @CommonsWare comment.. Probably you can rethink your approach..

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with this approach is that onDestroy() is not guaranteed to get called if the OS is killing the process. The same is true for onPause() on devices running pre-honeycomb versions of Android.