# how can you stop a service outside of an activity?

Tags: java, android, background-process

I'm making a litle game in android studio where I want background music to play when the user is interacting with the application (and have it turned on in the settings). For this I used a service for playing backgroundmusic. As you can see below

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class BackgroundMusicService extends Service {
    MediaPlayer player;
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.backgroundmusic);
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
    }
}
```

I want my backgroundmusic to play on all my activities, but stop when the user leaves the application, as it is impossible to detect a menu button press or a home button press in android. I tried to solve it like this.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class LeaveAppDetector extends BackgroundMusicService{
    private boolean Deactivated;
    private int Time = 700;
    private int wait = 0;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    public void Activate() {
        Deactivated = false;
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (wait >= 1) {
                    if (!getDeactivate()) {
                        //app has been closed
                        StopPlaying();
                        StopTimer();
                    } else {StopTimer();} //app has not been closed
                }
                wait++;
            }
        }, Time);
    }

    public void Deactivate() { //call at the start of each activity
        Deactivated = true;
    }

    private boolean getDeactivate() {
        return Deactivated;
    }

    private void StopTimer() {
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer.purge();
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that when an activity starts, it calls Deactivate(); and when it closes, it calls Activate(); so that the value of Activated is updated after a short period of time. I added the following method to my BackgrondMusicService class in order to be able to turn it off remotely

```
public void StopPlaying() {
    player.stop();
    player.release();
}
```

Now the problem, it gives me the error that the reference to the mediaplayers in the method I just showed, is one referring to a null object, and I don't know why or why it won't work. Can someone help?

Comment: Try stop service in `onDestroy` or `onPause` method from `Activity` and start it in `onCreate` or `onResume`.

Comment: You could register your Service to a `BroadcastReceiver` and register for a custom intent that you send each time you enter the settings, or the user interacts with the UI. This is what I'm using to send actions to the Service.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Bound Service like this answer suggest:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2660696/3742122

> If you only want the service running while activities are using it, consider getting rid of startService(). Instead, use bindService() in the onStart() methods of the activities that need the service, and call unbindService() in their corresponding onStop() methods. You can use BIND_AUTO_CREATE to have the service be lazy-started when needed, and Android will automatically stop the service after all connections have been unbound.